# C++ file output only accepts the first word

Tags: c++, string, file, file-io, fstream

I'm trying to output a string to a basic .txt file. And it only partially works, and by that I mean that it only accepts the first word of whatever I type. I need to be able to have no character limit as well (the user can type in however much they want)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;

    in_stream.open("advice.txt");
    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
     cout << "input file opening failed.\n";
     exit(1);                     
    }


    char next;

    in_stream.get(next);
    while (! in_stream.eof())
    {
     cout << next;
     in_stream.get(next);      
    }


    out_stream.open("advice.txt", ios::app); //Append data to file
    if (out_stream.fail())
    {
     cout << "output file opening failed.\n";
     exit(1);                     
    }


    //Output text into the file (Problem is in here)

    string mystring;

    cin >> mystring, "\n\n";
    out_stream << " - " << mystring << "\n\n";

    in_stream.close();
    out_stream.close();

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Any future help will be greatly appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extraction operator truncates on whitespaces. Use [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the entire line.

Instead of:

```
cin >> mystring, "\n\n";
```

Make it:

```
std::getline( std::cin, mystring );
```

Comment: Where exactly do i place this in reference to my code? does it replace my cin statement? where do i put it in reference to my out_stream?